# Vhdl parser on C#

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, vhdl

I need to make a vhdl parser. I decided to use the antlr parser generator and the vhdl grammar from their website http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1202750770887/vhdl.g.
I am having problems when checking the grammar and have this error:

> The following token definitions can never be matched because prior
>   tokens match the same input: LETTER,INTEGER,DIGIT...

If anyone has worked with this before, please tell me if the grammar is incorrect or if I'm doing something else incorrectly.

Comment: Can you show us the parser rule in your code that triggers this error message?

Answer (score 2):

From vhdl.g

```
BASIC_IDENTIFIER
   :   LETTER ( '_' | LETTER | DIGIT )*
   ;

...

LETTER  
  :  'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z'
  ;
```

LETTER, INTEGER and DIGIT all look like they should be a fragment, as they are never called by parser rules.

```
fragment LETTER 
  :  'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z'
  ;
```

EDIT: As Bart has stated, since BASIC_IDENTIFIER is listed before LETTER in the grammar and covers all the cases LETTER does, the lexer will never create any LETTER tokens. This is what is causing the warnings.

Comment: The fact that they are never called from any parser (or lexer) rules is not the problem: it's because a `LETTER` can never become a token on it's own since other rules, like `BASIC_IDENTIFIER` will match what a `LETTER` also matches. This indeed can be solved by making them `fragment`s.